# How to share Redis Connection / RedisCache in Symfony between services / controllers?

Tags: symfony, redis

I have a some Controllers, Twig Extensions and other classes that all need caching. I'm using Redis as a cache. Currently I setup a new RedisCache in each of these places, like so:

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;


    $this->cache = new RedisCache(RedisAdapter::createConnection(getenv('REDIS_URL')), 'ImageHelper');
}
```

But this creates many connections to the Redis backend, which I believe is not good for performance.

What is the best way to either share a RedisConnection/Client between my Controllers/extensions/classes, or even share the RedisCache, but keep namespacing ability?

I'm using Symfony 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the Redis cache a service, and inject it into your controllers (or other dependents) later on. Refer to Symfony's [dependency injection docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html) if needed.

Here's an example, you might need to fine-tune it later on:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    redis_connection:
        class: 'RedisConnection'
        factory: ['RedisAdapter', createConnection]
        arguments: 
          - '%env(REDIS_URL)%'

    redis_cache:
        class: 'RedisCache'
        arguments:
          - '@redis_connection'
```

Note that I don't know which namespaces your classes have, so you'd have to adjust the config accordingly.

And then you would also have to set up the framework to inject the service to your controllers (or other dependents):

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
  # ...
  App\Controller\ExampleController:
      arguments:
        - '@logger'
        - '@redis_cache'
```

Also, you should update the controllers to accept the new argument in constructor, like so:

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, RedisCache $cache)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

Refer to the [service container documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to works, however I'm not sure that multiple caches share the same RedisConnection, I'm new to Redis, but it looks like the connection count from the redis stats goes up by 3 each time I load a page. Could it be that since createConnection is a static method, it then get's called on each cache I define?

Comment: I also had to change the class names to their fully qualified path:
`redis_connection:
        class: 'RedisConnection'
        factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', createConnection]
        arguments:
            - '%env(REDIS_URL)%'

    redis_cache:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\RedisCache'
        arguments:
            - '@redis_connection'
            - 'NS'

    redis_cache.image_helper:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\RedisCache'
        arguments:
            - '@redis_connection'
            - 'NS2'
`